# Разработка медицинского сайта на yii2

Tags: yii2

Поставлена задача разработать медицинский портал на yii2.

У меня есть вопросы и отсутствие знания, такие как :

- Как создать визуальный редактор в этом фреймворке для редактирования страниц?
- Можно прикрутить к нему уже существующие панели или редакторы?
- Где можно найти больше информации по этой теме?

Comment: WYSIWYG HTML Editor. Информацию можно найти в поисковиках

Comment: по поиску yii2 tinymce можно найти много разных решений с описанием работы

Comment: Нашел что искал, спс